# Separate sitemap to multiple files

Tags: php, xml, opencart, sitemap

I'm using opencart 2 and default sitemap generator generate everything in one file I mean all products,category,image and so on , its take a long time when you open the file . How can I make something like:

products to be stored in `sitemap-product.xml`

category to be stored in `sitemap-category.xml`

image to be stored in `sitemap-image.xml`

and all to append to `sitemap.xml`

```
public function index() {
    if ($this->config->get('google_sitemap_status')) {
        $output  = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
        $output .= '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">';

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        $products = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts();

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            if ($product['image']) {
                $output .= '<url>';
                $output .= '<loc>' . $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id']) . '</loc>';
                $output .= '<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>';
                $output .= '<priority>1.0</priority>';
                $output .= '<image:image>';
                $output .= '<image:loc>' . $this->model_tool_image->resize($product['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_popup_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_popup_height')) . '</image:loc>';
                $output .= '<image:caption>' . $product['name'] . '</image:caption>';
                $output .= '<image:title>' . $product['name'] . '</image:title>';
                $output .= '</image:image>';
                $output .= '</url>';
            }
        }

        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        $output .= $this->getCategories(0);

        $this->load->model('catalog/manufacturer');

        $manufacturers = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturers();

        foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) {
            $output .= '<url>';
            $output .= '<loc>' . $this->url->link('product/manufacturer/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $manufacturer['manufacturer_id']) . '</loc>';
            $output .= '<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>';
            $output .= '<priority>0.7</priority>';
            $output .= '</url>';

            $products = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts(array('filter_manufacturer_id' => $manufacturer['manufacturer_id']));

            foreach ($products as $product) {
                $output .= '<url>';
                $output .= '<loc>' . $this->url->link('product/product', 'manufacturer_id=' . $manufacturer['manufacturer_id'] . '&product_id=' . $product['product_id']) . '</loc>';
                $output .= '<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>';
                $output .= '<priority>1.0</priority>';
                $output .= '</url>';
            }
        }

        $this->load->model('catalog/information');

        $informations = $this->model_catalog_information->getInformations();

        foreach ($informations as $information) {
            $output .= '<url>';
            $output .= '<loc>' . $this->url->link('information/information', 'information_id=' . $information['information_id']) . '</loc>';
            $output .= '<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>';
            $output .= '<priority>0.5</priority>';
            $output .= '</url>';
        }

        $output .= '</urlset>';

        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/xml');
        $this->response->setOutput($output);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does all this code do? What is missing? What have you tried to fill the missing parts?

Comment: @Nico Haase is missing the part for getCategories() function only , system do not allowed me to put more code ... i didnt tried anything because i have no idea how this can be done , but that is all how system generate the sitemap atm and rerwite url to the sitemap.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is simple. The controller you are trying to extend is the url:

> index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap
>   or
>   index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap if you are using opencart 2.3.x

The above url loads public function index(), so it's the same as:

> index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap/index

Now, copy public function index () and create a new function with name products. It should look like this:

```
public function products() {
    if ($this->config->get('google_sitemap_status')) {
        $output  = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
        $output .= '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">';

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        $products = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts();

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            if ($product['image']) {
                $output .= '<url>';
                $output .= '<loc>' . $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id']) . '</loc>';
                $output .= '<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>';
                $output .= '<priority>1.0</priority>';
                $output .= '<image:image>';
                $output .= '<image:loc>' . $this->model_tool_image->resize($product['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_popup_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_popup_height')) . '</image:loc>';
                $output .= '<image:caption>' . $product['name'] . '</image:caption>';
                $output .= '<image:title>' . $product['name'] . '</image:title>';
                $output .= '</image:image>';
                $output .= '</url>';
            }
        }

        $output .= '</urlset>';

        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/xml');
        $this->response->setOutput($output);
    }
}
```

Now if call the url:

> index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap/products

it should load only the products. It won't create the file you want, but it will create the sitemap xml for products on the fly.

**Edit / Additional info** :
If you have thousands of products you can add some limits easily.

```
public function products() {
    if ($this->config->get('google_sitemap_status')) {
        $output  = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
        $output .= '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">';

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        $data = [];

        if (isset($this->request->get['start'])) {
            $data['start'] = $this->request->get['start'];
        } else {
            $data['start'] = 0;

        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $data['limit'] = $this->request->get['limit'];
        } else {
            $data['limit'] = 2000; /* Change the default value for the limit */
        }

        $products = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($data);

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            if ($product['image']) {
                $output .= '<url>';
                $output .= '<loc>' . $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id']) . '</loc>';
                $output .= '<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>';
                $output .= '<priority>1.0</priority>';
                $output .= '<image:image>';
                $output .= '<image:loc>' . $this->model_tool_image->resize($product['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_popup_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_popup_height')) . '</image:loc>';
                $output .= '<image:caption>' . $product['name'] . '</image:caption>';
                $output .= '<image:title>' . $product['name'] . '</image:title>';
                $output .= '</image:image>';
                $output .= '</url>';
            }
        }

        $output .= '</urlset>';

        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/xml');
        $this->response->setOutput($output);
    }
}
```

Let's say that you have 50000 products. 
Example of the url to get the first 25000 products:

> index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap/products&start=0&limit=25000

Then get the rest 25000 products

> index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap/products&start=25000&limit=25000

---

You can do the same for categories, images, information pages etc.

PS: Of course to load the above urls, you need to add your domain name as prefix :D

Hope this helped you.

Comment: this work well but still 50.000 products in one xml its a lot is there any way i can split them in few files each of them with 10.000 results ?

Comment: I updated my answer by adding limitation. So now you can query with limits. You can create multiple sitemaps like this. Please check above.